# Leaflet.js working with move and zoom events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, leaflet

I would want to know how to work with Leaflet.js, capturing events when I move arround the map (dragging) or zooming on it.

I need to put some markers on my map and load more when I move around (or unload the ones not showed in the next position) or when I change the zoom level.

Could you help me with some examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution I found:

```
// Setting the CartoDB tile (you can use any tile you want)
var tile = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
              bounds: [[-90,-180],[90,180]],
              attribution:'&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>',
              subdomains:'abcd'
});

// Setting the map parameters
var map = L.map('map', {
        maxBounds: [[-90,-180],[90,180]],,
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 18,
        fullscreenControl: true
    })
    .addLayer(tile)
    .setView([0, 0], 12);

// Here the events for zooming and dragging
map.on('zoomend', function() {
   // stuff here when user zooms the map...
});
map.on('dragend', function() {
   // stuff here when user drags the map...    
});
```

And that's all. Simply :)

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
  .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
  .openPopup();
  
L.marker([51, -0.09]).addTo(map)
  .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
  .openPopup();
  
  //just keep adding more L.markers and coordinates and they should populate on the map
```

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>


<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: But this just put markers on the map. I want that, if I have markers all over the world and I'm over London... I don't want the New York markers are already loaded (only if I see New York in the map)

Comment: have you look at this? https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-list-markers this might be what you're looking for.  Seems fairness to implement

Comment: No, it just tells you which markers are shown in the map, but the markers are there (visible or not).

Comment: I'm confused.  So all markers should be loaded and you should only see markers in your current location?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. If I'm situated in New York, I just want to see the markers of New York, but only the ones that are inside the area I am (visible).

Comment: gotcha, I'll see what I can come up with